# Filters in SharpPcap

Tags: c#, filter, sharppcap

Im trying to filter out just he Probes and Broadcast frames on the wifi.

Using SharpPcap.

```
((SharpPcap.AirPcap.AirPcapDevice)(device)).Filter = "wlan.fc.type eq 0";
```

does not work

same with

```
((SharpPcap.AirPcap.AirPcapDevice)(device)).Filter = "wlan.fc.type == 0";
```

This lines seems to allow Broadcast

```
((SharpPcap.AirPcap.AirPcapDevice)(device)).Filter = "broadcast";
```

but need to really get all managent frames.

Comment: The filters should match what tcpdump and wireshark use so you can test out your filters there and then use them with sharppcap. Are those filters working as expected in wireshark?

Comment: Yeah they work 100% in wireshark, and thats where i got the filters from.

Comment: Other filters seem to work just nothing that seems to start wlan.fc etc

Comment: I don't think SharpPcap supports it

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the following: Wireshark decodes the packets, so when you apply those filters the packets are already decoded, thus are able to access wlan.fc.type field.

Based on my personal experience and SharpPcap usage, the Filter you're trying to use is computed on a byte[], so you need to be way more specific to be sure it's applied properly.

For example, I've been using this filter for my purpose.

```
private const String filteringSV = "(ether[0:4] = 0x010CCD04)";
```

Additionally, remember to set the filter only on an already opened device.

```
if (nicToUse != null)
         {
            try
            {
               nicToUse.OnPacketArrival -= OnPackectArrivalLive;
               nicToUse.OnPacketArrival += OnPackectArrivalLive;
               try
               {
                  if (nicToUse.Started)
                     nicToUse.StopCapture();
                  if (nicToUse.Opened)
                     nicToUse.Close();
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                  //no handling, just do it.
               }

               nicToUse.Open(OpenFlags.Promiscuous|OpenFlags.MaxResponsiveness,10);                 

               nicToUse.Filter = "(ether[0:4] = 0x010CCD04)";

               nicToUse.StartCapture();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception(Resources.SharpPCapPacketsProducer_Start_Error_while_starting_online_capture_, ex);
            }
         }
```

Hope it helped.